# ' symbol in BibTeX style file

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to read about `.bst` files from [Tame the Beast](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf). On page 38, there is this example for an `and` function:

```
FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
```

What does the `'` in front of `skip` do?

Comment 34 on page 32 says:

> A variable name is a name that has been declared with STRINGS or INTEGERS, or with ENTRY. Moreover, it must be preceded with a single quote, so that BibTeX understands that you mean the name of the variable and not its value. For instance, ’label.

It still doesn't make sense that `skip` is a variable name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before we look at the underlying idea, it's important to remember that `and` in BibTeX is a comparator hidden inside a function. It's always used after something that will generate an integer, which will then either be `1` (TRUE) or `0` (FALSE). It's sorting out the logic of comparing two integers, but it only does something with the second one as the result is whatever the first integer is.

The `'` here is used to allow 'simplification' of the code. The standard syntax for a conditional is

```
<number>
  { <code if true> }
  { <code if false> }
if$
```

Notice in particular that both branches require a set of braces. (BibTeX's `if$` tests a number on a simple TRUE/FALSE = 1/0 basis. Most conditionals you'll see in BibTeX have a part before the `if$` doing a bit of work to set this up.)

In the example, the TRUE branch consists of a BibTeX built-in only. Thus while you could write

```
FUNCTION {and}
{
    { skip$ }
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
```

or

```
FUNCTION {and}
{
    { }
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
```

this makes the TRUE branch a bit tricky to read. Thus there is a 'shortcut' syntax: the braces may be missed out if you use `'skip$` in place of `{ skip$ }`.

You normally only see this approach for branches being skipped, as it's not really so useful with other built-ins (although you might see `'pop$` in the same way).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! A couple of questions:

1) "the TRUE branch consists of a BibTeX built-in" >> What is a BibTeX built-in?

2) Why is `{ skip$ }` trickier to read than `'skip$`? I found the first one more natural.

Comment: @MikaH. BibTeX has a small number of built-in functions, all of which end `$`, for example `skip$`, `pop$`, `if$`. I'm contrasting them with functions defined in a `.bst` file, such as `and` in the example.

Comment: @MikaH. On the readability or otherwise: both approaches will work, so it's down to you how you approach this. In the LaTeX3 coding I do we've also decided that omitting braces does not necessarily help with readability! One thing to bear in mind is that parsing a `{ ... }` expression is more work than an single statement, and while this is not important now, computers were a lot less powerful historically.

Comment: I'ts frustrating that this is not mentioned in the documentation... which makes `'skip$` _much_ harder to read than `{skip$}`!!